# Complementary function / particular integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function $y(x)$ satisfies
$$
x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + (1-2a)x \frac{dy}{dx} + a^2 y = 3x^b,
$$
where a and b are real parameters.

Can somebody explain how to find the complementary function for this and how I would find what the particular integral would be where it is  $b \neq - a$.

I have been grappling with the concept for the complementary function that $ycf(x)$ is equal to $A(x) + B(x)$ where they are constants but it is just going entirely over my head right now, especially the particular integral to the ODE.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for MathJax.

Comment: @innerproduct Thank you!

Comment: Just want to chime in and say that this is a standard Cauchy-Euler equation, and we always proceed by substituting $x=e^t$, like the below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + (1-2a)x \frac{dy}{dx} + a^2 y = 3x^b$$
Change the variable $y(x)  \to y(t)$:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} -2a \frac{dy}{dt} + a^2 y = 3e^{tb}$$
Where $x=e^t$ and solve. You can also substitute again  $u=ta$ for $a\ne 0$. Then it's easier to solve.
$$\frac{d^2 y}{du^2} -2 \frac{dy}{du} + y = \dfrac 3 {a^2}e^{ub/a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering first
$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + (1-2a)x \frac{dy}{dx} + a^2 y =0$$
try $y=x^k z$ to make
$$x \left((2 k-2a+1) z'+x z''\right)+(a-k)^2 z(x)=0$$ Using $k=a$ looks interesting and leads to
$$x z''+z'=0$$
SO, the full equation is now
$$x z''+z'=3 x^{b-a-1}\implies (x\,z')'=3 x^{b-a-1}$$ This does not seem difficult.